# How to get divs on to new line

Tags: css

See the following codepen for demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGPJOG

```
<div class="col-1-3 bg-green">green</div>

<div class="col-1-3 bg-green">

    <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">
        blue<br/>blue<br/>blue<br/>blue<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">
        blue
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">
        blue
    </div>

</div>

<div class="col-1-3 bg-green">green</div>

<div class="col-1-3 bg-pink">pink</div>
<div class="col-1-3 bg-pink">pink</div>
<div class="col-1-3 bg-pink">pink</div>
```

I have two rows/sets of cells, first row/set has green background, second has pink.
Inside one of the cells (second) in the first row/set, the green one, I have a nested row/set which has the colour blue.

My question is, how do I get the pink row/set to show up on a new line, below the first! green cell. currently the pink ones gets stacked under the last green cell.

I believe this is where I need to use clearfix solutions, and wrap each set of cells in yet another div and call it 'row' for example.
Is there a way to do it without a 'row' wrapper, I feel there should be, as long as the cells add up to 100% width.

Desired result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GYSj.jpg

thanks in advance!

Comment: ?? you could remove the class `.col-1-3`  from the first div ?

Comment: What do you want the final result to be? 3 sets of colors next to each other?

Comment: 3 .col-1-3 adds up to 100% of the width, so i want it two be green first, then below it pink. (but the nested blue will be in the middle green cell)
Desire result: http://imgur.com/a/8pdry

Comment: Try to use on the pink with col-md-4

Comment: GrowingDev: sorry, i'm not following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this after the 3rd green div:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

then add this to your css:

```
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

Or you can also clear every third + 1 `.col-1-3` child (without the extra div):

```
.col-1-3:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear:left;
}
```

Or with a clear class which you add to every first element of a row:

```
.col-first {
    clear:left;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Not sure I fully understand it though, is there any way to put it on the last green div and not having to create an empty div?

Comment: Yep, I updated the answer with a different approach (w/o the div).

Comment: so wohever is last, should have clear:left then, as it might be a col-2-3 that is the last.

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to wrap them in a row.

Comment: I'm doing my own grid, just to learn css better. I've been reading other grids code, and basically trying to see if there is a way to get rid of the "row" class. This example uses 3 cells, but my final will probably have 12. So perhaps a "row" class is needed after all. Or maybe a "last" class, to add to the last cell, to clear left?

Comment: It should be a "first" though, so every first element of a row.

Comment: ah, that's what Johannes answer does as well, except its clear:both instead of clear:left. . I guess this will not work if I later want to make this grid responsive, a "row" wrapper class is needed then no? Thanks for your help as well!

Comment: Yes Johannes answer definately works as well, there's alot of possibilities. And to make it responsive you do not necessarily need a row. Try to experiment more with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to the first pink element which clears the floating. In my codepen I added class "clearleft" to the first pink div, then added the following CSS rule:

```
.clearleft {
  clear:left;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjprVm

Comment: Thank you Johannes. Why clear both, and not just left if i may ask?

Comment: As i had added, left works as well, I just had the both already put into the codepen (so I left it in my answer), but it's not really necessary.

Comment: I edited my answer and the codepen now to only include `clear: left`

Comment: thanks again Johannes. wish i could set two answers as correct

Comment: I did, but i have less than 15 in rep so it wont show.